# USQL - SQL.ARRAY get length?

Tags: azure, u-sql

For the context, I get data from a sensor and it store in string like this

```
"axes" : "...,1,23,21,0,12,10,212,12,..."
```

the size may change depending on the machine sending the data... So my goal is to store it like a SQL.ARRAY and I want to get the size of this array later to perform some bussiness report.

Is there a way to find the length of SQL.ARRAY ?

```
@outputfile =
    SELECT m.MachineID,
           COUNT( * ) AS nbAxesArray
    FROM MachineInfos AS m
         JOIN
             LoadDataAxes AS lda
         ON m.EventIoTID == lda.EventIoTID
         //WHERE getLength(lda.L) == 0 // something like this
    GROUP BY m.MachineID;
```

Comment: Can I just check, is the sensor data provided as json, or exactly as you've specified?

Comment: The sensor data is provided as json like this ...{"Axes":[{"N":"Z1","L":"23;23;22;0;..."}, {"N":"X1"...}, ...]}. I have a table where I  store the Axes with the column -> EventID(Int64?), N(string),  and L(SQL.ARRAY<string>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SQL.ARRAY` complex type has a number of methods, like `Count` and implements [IEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0(v=vs.110).aspx) under the hood*.

A simple example:

```
DECLARE @outputFile string = @"output/output.csv";

@input =
    SELECT *
    FROM ( VALUES 
        ( 100, "1,23,21,0,12,10,212,12" ),
        ( 101, "7,8,9" )
         ) AS x(rowId, y);


// Convert the string to array
@working =
    SELECT rowId, new SQL.ARRAY<string>(y.Split(',')) AS z
    FROM @input;


/*
// Explode the array to individual rows
@output =
    SELECT b
    FROM @working
         CROSS APPLY
             EXPLODE(z) AS a(b);
*/

@output =
    SELECT rowId, z.Count AS c
    FROM @working;


OUTPUT @output
TO @outputFile
USING Outputters.Csv(quoting:false);
```

*(I think)

My results:

[image: Results]

Some other examples [here](https://saveenr.gitbooks.io/usql-tutorial/content/complex-types/arrays.html).  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks !! I was looking for the ```Count``` method :) and the link is really usefull too !